# How to create a subscriber in shopware 6 custom plugin?

Tags: php, shopware6

I create a plugin, and I need, when home page is loading, I get random product and show.

This is my Subscriber getRandomProduct class:

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ThemeCompilerEnrichScssVariablesEvent::class => 'getRandomProduct'
    ];
}

public function getRandomProduct(ThemeCompilerEnrichScssVariablesEvent $event): void
{

    dd('s');
}
```

But when I refresh homepage, there is no action.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that `ThemeCompilerEnrichScssVariablesEvent` is the correct event to use for that purpose? As the name suggests, this is for enriching the variables during the compilation of scss ressources. That's not happening on every request.

See the documentation on how to [add data to the storefront](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-data-to-storefront-page) page.